# how to covert import from to require nodeJs

Tags: node.js

in my NodeJS project i tried to add expo SDK for notification
but I have to use import while my all project using require
I wont add type : module in package.json

I tried to change it like this but here is error

```
- import { Expo } from "expo-server-sdk";
+ const Expo = require("expo-server-sdk")
```

error if i use import

```
import { Expo } from "expo-server-sdk";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

the error if i use require

```
let expo = new Expo({ accessToken: process.env.EXPO_TOKEN });
             ^

TypeError: Expo is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

i get it now
when i use require its point to the file so i want to call the Expo class

```
const expoObj = require("expo-server-sdk");
let expo = new expoObj.Expo({ accessToken: process.env.EXPO_TOKEN });
```

Comment: You can also write `const { Expo } = require("expo-server-sdk");` and not have to use `expoObj`.